# Node.js ajax post to mongodb

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb

I'm having problem with sending data from ajax client to nodejs and storing that data in a collection in mongodb.
Here's my client code:

```
testdata = {'test1':'test1', 'test2':'test2'}
  for(i=0;i<2;i++){          // for testing purposes
    $(".btn").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/1',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: testdata ,
            success: function(){
                console.log(i);
            }

        });
    }); 
 }
```

And my node.js server post handler with express:

```
app.post('/1', function(req, res){
db.collection('test', function(err, collection){
    var data = req.body;
        collection.insert(data, function (err, result) {
            if(!err){
                console.log(result);
            }else{
                res.end();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Body parser middleware is on, mongo is on of course, but my test collection is not receiving any data. I have a sence that i'm missing something very obvious here. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Having you tried console.log(data) in your node app to see that you're at least receiving the data correctly?

Comment: Yes i wasn't getting anything in req.body. Turned out to be very stupid thing, i had another function that handled the same route and it was the cause of my problem. I need to organize my code... :)